# ASP.NET Cookieless Forms Auth not setting cookie when Login page is bookmarked

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, cookieless

Our ASP.NET 4.0 application's forms authentication is set to cookieless="AutoDetect."  I've noticed that if a user bookmarks our login page, the bookmark link is set to https://hostname.com/Login.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1.  If a user navigates to this directly from a new browser session and performs a valid login, the cookie is not set.  If I navigate directly to that page, bu remove AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport from the query string, the cookie is created correctly.

If a user navigates directly to Default.aspx or the root directory, login functions correctly, even with AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1 tacked on to the query string.

When the user clicks the login button, we do a postback to the login page and manually check the users credentials against our database.  If successful, we do:

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userName, false);
```

I've spent many hours debugging this, including looking at the ASP.NET forms authentication code in the reference source, and haven't been able to determine what is causing this.  The only solution we have at the moment is telling users to remove the Login page from their bookmark URL and adding a bookmark button on our Login page for users to click.

Is there another solution to fix this forms authentication issue?  Is it a but in forms authentication?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are always using the RedirectFromLoginPage, whether or not the redirect location is provided. If it is not provided, then the redirect will fail. A proper solution to this would be to check the redirect url and redirect to the default.aspx if it is not available (source example borrowed from [this blog article](http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2005/04/25/37612.aspx)):

```
// Once the user's entered credentials are verified //
if(Request.Params["ReturnUrl"] != null)
{
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtUserName.text, false);
}
else
{
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthcookie(txtUserName.text, false);
    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response to your answer. I seem to be getting the problem whether or not ReturnUrl is in the QueryString. I actually tried your code on my local machine running in IIS 7.5 and it worked somehow. I copied the same DLL to our test server and it continue with the same problem. It seems like a fluke in forms authentication.

Answer (score 0):

To remove this, add cookieless property of sessionState in your web.config to false.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="20" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

or

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="20" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```